# jQuery Mobile horizontal scrollable divs (dynamic multiple columns but 1 row)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way in jQuery Mobile to create a layout with dynamic multiple columns that is scrollable horizontally. (Something like a infinite carousel / picture slideshow but with DIVs and not images.)

Comment: You may want to take a look at [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll). This can be used for vertical and horizontal scrollers

Comment: I expected a framwork support. Btw, iScroll does not support JQM out-of-box, still we may need to wrap it up to work fine across all the phones/browsers.

Comment: Seems that iScroll can be used with jQm if setup correctly see (here)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549806/jquery-mobile-css-scroll-and-click]

Comment: Thanks and now able to perform horizontal scroll using iScroll4. After having compared with Sencha touch scrolling, still it does not quite give a native scrolling effect in iOS (ipad and iphone) - Is there any other plugin you can recommend for jQuery Mobile?

Comment: For a project I am using (an older version of) jQTouch from DataZombies because of the non-existence of jQM at the time I developed my project. The scroll in there (iScroll) I think looks quite ok.

Comment: Well, I settled with iScroll for time being and felt its good to go! Thanks.

Comment: added my comment as answer, so you can accept it as answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [iScroll-4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4). This can be used for vertical and horizontal scrollers